# Use managed service account with ELMAH to send email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

Is it possible to use a Windows managed service account to send [ELMAH](https://github.com/elmah/Elmah) exceptions? Here's a sample `errorEmail` from `Web.config`; would it still have a `password` attribute?

```
<elmah>
    <errorMail from="someemail@mydomain.com" to="someemail@mydomain.com" async="true" 
        subject="MyApp Exception thrown: {0}" userName="someemail@mydomain.com" 
        password="" smtpServer="smtp.mydomain.org"/>
</elmah>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. So, you want to leave out the `userName` and `password` attributes and let ELMAH use the current user, or?

Comment: @ThomasArdal, thanks for your reply. Windows managed service accounts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview) hide the password and change it automatically. From what I'm reading, it's not possible to use them to send emails: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ff641729(v=ws.10)#supported-technologies

Comment: I see. I'm afraid I don't know enough about managed service accounts to give you a good answer then :)

Comment: @ThomasArdal, no worries. Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't need to use an MSA; answer was too simple: don't include the credentials in the `errorMail` properties:

```
<elmah>
     <errorMail from="noreply@mydomain.com" to="someemail@mydomain.com" 
          async="true" subject="MyApp Exception thrown: {0}" 
          smtpServer="smtp.mydomain.org"/>
</elmah>
```

Note we also changed the "from" to a fake "noreply" email, as we don't want replies. Also, we can't use a Win service account to send emails, as [described by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ff641729(v=ws.10)#supported-technologies):

> Exchange Server does not allow you to send e-mails from a managed
>   service account on behalf of a service or application. To overcome
>   this limitation, use the managed service account to run the service,
>   but create a separate conventional user account for the service and
>   configure the service to send e-mails using this account.

That's for Server 2008 but seems to be true for the latest ones as well. Special thanks to our Ops team for this answer.